# Many Monicas in Stack Exchange but who were they before?

Tags: discussion

Over the years I've built up an understanding of regular members. How they tend to answer, their areas of expertise, even a certain amount of behavior predictability.

With the recent trend of putting "Monica" in their user ID I'm loosing touch with some long term member personality traits I had acquired.

Looking at their new member profile is there anyway of seeing their name history?

Case in Point: https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/justice-for-monica

PS: I fully support people speaking their minds and protesting peacefully, even if I disagree with them.

---

## Who is Monica?

Based on comments I'll update this question with this screenshot:

[image: Gilles profile.png]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116801/make-the-past-names-list-public-info-for-30-days-after-changing-your-name and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317640/how-to-obtain-the-user-name-history-of-a-user TLDR; No, not unless you are a mod.

Comment: @MarkKirby Kuffy below has a cool idea.

Comment: That's why some left their old name and just added onto it - IMHO, that's a nicer way to do it, precisely for the reason you mention.

Comment: @JonasCz-ReinstateMonica Yesterday I noticed Gilles did that and I appreciated how much easier that makes life. And of course I thank you for doing that too!

Comment: Who is Monica??

Comment: @Pilot6 Have you read Seth's resignation post on meta?

Comment: @Kuffy Yes I did read that post.

Comment: @Pilot6 Monica's full name is Monica Cellio. She was a mod on a bunch of SE sites like MSE, Judaism, Mi-Yodeya, etc. She was fired by SE from the position of mod on all sites. See her meta post on Mi-Yodeya and 2nd most upvoted question on MSE to know more. **PS:** I'm Ku**lf**y.

Comment: @Kuffy Thanks a lot. I didn't have a clue which Monica was meant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) to the rescue. Just enter the link of any post made by that user. If you are lucky enough, their post with their previous display name would appear.

In your particular example, [Justice for Monica](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/) is DK Bose.

Moreover IIRC, only moderators can see the previously used display names.

Comment: Ahh DK Bose was the first person to bring Monica to my attention. I haven't seen posts by DK Bose in a long time and it all makes sense now :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I think it's the other way around. Wanderer posted something in Chat to which you responded and I noticed. Links, in chronological order, follow:

Comment: [1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51884642#51884642), [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51885140#51885140), [3](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51885408#51885408), [4](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51887583#51887583), & [5](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51953772#51953772)